# helloworld in play framework in eclipse

Tags: playframework

i am new to PLAY frame work , if some one could just help me how to create a simple helloworld application in PLAY in eclipse IDE.
I have already put the play jar file to eclipse dropins.

I have these "new controller", "new view", "new model", "fo to route" options in Eclipse.

How to write HelloWorld in Play (with eclipse).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should have a look at

‘Hello World’ tutorial — Your first Play application

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/firstapp (Play 1.0)

and

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/latest/IDE

if you speak spanish go to http://playdoces.appspot.com

If you are intrested in using play with activator then check this out -

https://quintupledev.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/play-framework-intro-hello-world/